# Association in Linq To SQL showing as an EntitySet<>, why?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am having a lot of trouble coming up with the Linq equivalent of this legacy stored procedure.  The biggest hurdle is  <strike>it doesn't seem to want to let me add a second 'clause' on the join with `tblAddress`.  I am getting a `Cannot resolve method...` error.</strike> that `tblBusiness.tblAddress` is seen as an `EntitySet<tblAddress>`  See bottom for current effort.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?  Below is, *first*, the `SPROC` I need to convert and, *second*, my `LINQ` attempt so far; which is **FULL OF FAIL!**

Thanks

```
SELECT dbo.tblPersonInsuranceCoverage.PersonInsuranceCoverageID, 
    dbo.tblPersonInsuranceCoverage.EffectiveDate, 
    dbo.tblPersonInsuranceCoverage.ExpirationDate, 
    dbo.tblPersonInsuranceCoverage.Priority, 
    dbo.tblAdminInsuranceCompanyType.TypeName AS CoverageCategory, 
    dbo.tblBusiness.BusinessName, 
    dbo.tblAdminInsuranceType.TypeName AS TypeName,
    CASE WHEN dbo.tblAddress.AddressLine1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE dbo.tblAddress.AddressLine1 END 
    + ' ' + 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tblAddress.CityName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '<BR>' + dbo.tblAddress.CityName END 
    + ' ' + 
    CASE WHEN dbo.tblAddress.StateID IS NULL THEN '' 
         WHEN dbo.tblAddress.StateID = 'ns' THEN '' 
         ELSE dbo.tblAddress.StateID END AS Address
FROM      
    dbo.tblPersonInsuranceCoverage 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblInsuranceCompany 
            ON dbo.tblPersonInsuranceCoverage.InsuranceCompanyID = dbo.tblInsuranceCompany.InsuranceCompanyID 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblBusiness     
                    ON dbo.tblBusiness.BusinessID = dbo.tblInsuranceCompany.BusinessID 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblAddress 
                            ON dbo.tblAddress.BusinessID = dbo.tblBusiness.BusinessID and tblAddress.AddressTypeID = 'b' 

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblAdminInsuranceCompanyType 
            ON dbo.tblPersonInsuranceCoverage.InsuranceCompanyTypeID = dbo.tblAdminInsuranceCompanyType.InsuranceCompanyTypeID  

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblAdminInsuranceType 
            ON dbo.tblPersonInsuranceCoverage.InsuranceTypeID = dbo.tblAdminInsuranceType.InsuranceTypeID   

WHERE tblPersonInsuranceCoverage.PersonID = @PersonID
```

---

```
 var coverage = 
                    from insuranceCoverage in context.tblPersonInsuranceCoverages
                    where insuranceCoverage.PersonID == personID

                select
                    new
                        {
                            insuranceCoverage.PersonInsuranceCoverageID,
                            insuranceCoverage.EffectiveDate,
                            insuranceCoverage.ExpirationDate,
                            insuranceCoverage.Priority,
                            CoverageCategory = insuranceCoverage.tblInsuranceCompany.tblAdminInsuranceCompanyType.TypeName,
                            insuranceCoverage.tblInsuranceCompany.tblBusiness.BusinessName,
                            TypeName = insuranceCoverage.InsuranceTypeID,
                            Address = insuranceCoverage.tblInsuranceCompany.tblBusiness.tblAddresses
                                                                        .Where(a => a.AddressTypeId = 'b')
                                                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                            };
```

### EDIT for further attempt

So I added some associations in the dbml so that I could take Craigs advice below.  It almost works.  Now I am getting a `Cannot resolve symbol` on `a.AddressTypeID`.  What is strange is that Intellisense tells me that `tblAddress` is an `EntitySet<tblAdress>`.  Am I missing an association or do I have an improper one or am I just TOO many levels deep?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's usually wrong (and way too much work) to use `join` in LINQ to SQL](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/). Instead, use the navigation/association properties L2S generates for you:

```
var coverage = 
                from insuranceCoverage in context.tblPersonInsuranceCoverages
                where insuranceCoverage.PersonID == personID
                select new
                    {
                            insuranceCoverage.PersonInsuranceCoverageID,
                            insuranceCoverage.EffectiveDate,
                            insuranceCoverage.ExpirationDate,
                            insuranceCoverage.Priority,
                            CoverageCategory = insuranceCoverage.insuranceCompany.tblAdminInsuranceCompanyType.TypeName,
                            insuranceCoverage.insuranceCompany.tblBusiness.BusinessName,
                            TypeName = insuranceCoverage.InsuranceTypeID,
                            Address = insuranceCoverage.insuranceCompany.Addresses
                                                                        .Where(a => a.AddressTypeID == 'b')
                                                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                        };
```

Comment: I agree, unfortunately I am not being given that option in Intellisense....I wonder why...

Comment: Okay, I went into the `dbml` and added some `associations`.  I have no idea why they weren't **ALL** generated automatically but I digress.  After that I was able to do as you suggested **EXCEPT** for the `ADDRESS` part.  See my edit for more details.  Thanks!

Comment: When you type `a.`, what does IntelliSense show you? You may need to do something like `a.AddressType.Id` (note extra dot).

Comment: Nevermind, I am an idiot.  It should have read `a.AddressTypeID == 'b'`  Notice the capital **D** and the second **=** wow!! anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it'll do everything you need, but you can use anonymous types for equijoins with a composite key:

```
 from x in table1
 join y in table2 on new { x.Id1, x.Id2 } equals new { y.Id1, y.Id2 }
 ...
```

See if that helps.